# Strange comportment in writing a single character in java

Tags: java, binary

I am trying to write a single character in a text file.

I do:

```
  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("exemple.txt"));
  out.write((char)174);
  out.close();
```

My text file is supposed to contains 10101110, if I look it with a binary viewer. Instead of it, it shows 11000010 10101110. So it writes 194 174, which is not the expected result.

So how can I write a single character in java which will result the good binary value ?

Comment: The thing to note is that anything over 127 is not an ASCII character and will be translated on output -- you must specify the translation or it will default to something you likely don't want.  And, of course, if your intent is to write binary rather than character data you should open the file in binary mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the file using the appropriate character set.  something like:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("c:\\exemple.txt"), "CP1252"));
```

i would suggest reading a good tutorial which teaches the difference between bytes and chars and what a character set is.

Comment: Correct charset is "CP1252" instead of "US-ASCII". It works, thank you!